# NSTimer or Something Else for an Image Unlock?

Tags: nstimer

How can you have an image or a button unlock at a certain time or date?  Basically, I want an image to be 'locked' until a specific time.

When that time has passed I would like for the image to be unlocked.

Any help or guidance is very appreciated.

Thanks.